# Stored procedure hangs seemingly without explanation

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

we have a stored procedure that ran fine until 10 minutes ago and then it just hangs after you call it.

Observations:

- Copying the code into a query window yields the query result in 1 second
- SP takes > 2.5 minutes until I cancel it
- Activity Monitor shows it's not being blocked by anything, it's just doing a SELECT.
- Running sp_recompile on the SP doesn't help
- Dropping and recreating the SP doesn't help
- Setting LOCK_TIMEOUT to 1 second does not help

What else can be going on?

---

**UPDATE**: I'm guessing it had to do with parameter sniffing. I used Adam Machanic's routine to find out which subquery was hanging. I found things wrong with the query plan thanks to the hint by Martin Smith. I learned about `EXEC ... WITH RECOMPILE`, `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` for subqueries within the SP, and `OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@parameter = 1))` in order to attack parameter sniffing. I still don't know what was wrong in this particular case but I came out of this battle seasoned and much better armed. I know what to do next time. So here's the points!

Comment: What does the execution plan look like? (You can use this query to get it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831644/why-does-a-database-query-only-go-slow-in-the-application/3831685#3831685) How does the plan compare with the plan when you copy the code into the query window and execute it?

Comment: Something's different - are variables being used when you paste the statement into a query window?

Comment: @OMG: The variables are 2 INTS and 2 DATES and are the same, I declared them at the beginning of the query window. And now (about half an hour later) the procedure is running again. Perhaps it was recompiling?

Comment: @Martin: The execution plan is visible only when the query is finished, and it never finishes. How can I view the query plan of an SP without running it?

Comment: @littlegreen - From `sys.dm_exec_cached_plans`. Did you look at the link?

Comment: Sounds like parameter sniffing -- view both of the query plans and you should see the difference

Comment: @etliens - Doesn't sound like parameter sniffing to me as recompiling or dropping and recreating the procedure didn't fix it.

Comment: @Martin Smith - You're right, I completely overlooked the recompilation.

Comment: @littlegreen - Another method to view the query plan is to run this in another session while the sp is running.



SELECT
    [query_plan]
FROM
    sys.dm_exec_requests
CROSS APPLY
    sys.dm_exec_query_plan(plan_handle) 
WHERE
    [session_id] = @@YOURSPID

Comment: @Martin: Oops, I didnt notice the link. I will try, I hope I can still find a difference now that the SP is running as normal again. Otherwise I'll have to look up this post once an SP is acting up again.

Comment: @etliens: Thanks! That'll be useful to me in the future.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Run Adam Machanic's excellent sp_WhoIsActive stored proc while your query is running.  It'll give you the wait information - meaning, what the stored proc is waiting on - plus things like the execution plan:

http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/09/sql-server-dba-scripts-how-to-find-slow-sql-server-queries/

If you want the outer command (like a calling stored procedure's full text), use the @get_outer_command = 1 parameter as well.

Comment: Might work, but it shows only active command by default, thus check https://stackoverflow.com/a/62962519/5113030.

Comment: @F8ER just use the parameter get_outer_command = 1 if you want the outer command. No need for extra scripts.

Answer (score 20):

I think that this is related to parameter sniffing and the need to parameterize your input params to local params within the SP. Adding with recompile causes the execution plan to be recreated and eliminates much of the benefits of having a SP. We were using With Recompile on many reports in an attempt to eliminate this hanging issue and it occassionally resulted in hanging SP's that may have been related to other locks and/or transactions accessing the same tables simultaneously. See this link for more details
[Parameter Sniffing (or Spoofing) in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211355/parameter-sniffing-or-spoofing-in-sql-server) and change your SP's to the following to fix this:

CREATE  PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPNAME] @p1 int, @p2 int
AS

DECLARE @localp1 int, @localp2 int

SET @localp1=@p1
SET @localp2=@p2

Comment: You are a genius.  This is the solution that saved my day.

Comment: This, unexpectedly, solved my issue with some SP's just randomly running in eternity. Just 350 SP's left to update now... ;)

Comment: Worked for me as well. Running the query manually worked fine - running from entity framework or exec just ran forever... changed the parameters to locals and they now run fine thanks

Comment: Very easy win, would not have believed such a simple solution could be so effective!

Comment: Jared, this is the most impressive tsql moment of wisdom of my year. Thank you. Problem solved...

Answer (score 5):

First thing First.

Please check if there are any uncommitted transactions. A begin transaction without "COMMIT TRANSACTION"

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all comments.

I still haven't found the answer, but I will post the progress here.

I failed to reproduce the problem before, but today I chanced upon another stored procedure with the same problem. Again the same symptoms appeared:

- Hanging piece of query runs fine and quick (3 secs) in normal query window (hanging piece identified with sp_whoisactive)
- No locks, according to Activity Monitor SPID is doing SELECT
- Stored procedure runs for over 6 hours without response
- Parameters passed to SP and variables declared in window are the same

Using above hints, I found the SP execution plan and it showed nothing out of the ordinary (to me, at least). Creating a new stored procedure with same contents did not solve the problem either. So I started stripping the SP to less and less contents until I encountered a **UDF call to another database**. When I removed that (replaced the call by the inline contents of the function, a `CASE` statement), it ran fine again.

So this COULD have been the problem, but I am not very certain, as last time the problem disappeared by itself and I also changed a lot of other things while stripping this SP.

Comment: Try adding "WITH RECOMPILE" to the stored proc. This will rebuild the query plan each time.

Comment: Thanks, didnt know about that one - will try it next time.

Comment: Links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211355/parameter-sniffing-or-spoofing-in-sql-server and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601939/stored-procedure-timing-out-drop-then-create-and-its-up-again/

Answer (score 1):

When we add new data sometimes the execution plan becomes invalid or out of date then the stored procedure starts going into this limbo phase. Run the following commands on your database

```
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS 

DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
```

It will  flush the cache memory and rebuild the execution plan next time you will run the stored proc.

[msdn.microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174283.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think I had the same problem.  I removed my parameters from the subqueries.  It ran fine after that.  Not sure if this is possible in your script but that is what solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

An answer of [Brent Ozar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3956108/5113030) might work, but it returns only active command text by default. For example, it returns `WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'` for query like:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetChangeNotifications
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE
        @actionType TINYINT;
    WHILE @actionType IS NULL
    BEGIN
        WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05';
        SELECT TOP 1
            @actionType = [ActionType]
        FROM
            TableChangeNotifications;
    END;
    SELECT
        TOP 1000 [RecordID], [Component], [TableName], [ActionType], [Key1], [Key2], [Key3]
    FROM
        TableChangeNotifications;
END;
```

How it looks like:

[image: How it looks like #1]

Thus, check the parameter `@get_outer_command` as described [here](http://whoisactive.com/docs/10_commands/).

Also, try this one instead(slightly modified procedure from [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-requests-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#d-ordering-existing-requests-by-cpu)):

```sql
DECLARE
    @sessions TABLE
(
    [SPID]        INT,
    STATUS        VARCHAR(MAX),
    [Login]       VARCHAR(MAX),
    [HostName]    VARCHAR(MAX),
    [BlkBy]       VARCHAR(MAX),
    [DBName]      VARCHAR(MAX),
    [Command]     VARCHAR(MAX),
    [CPUTime]     INT,
    [DiskIO]      INT,
    [LastBatch]   VARCHAR(MAX),
    [ProgramName] VARCHAR(MAX),
    [SPID_1]      INT,
    [REQUESTID]   INT
);

INSERT INTO @sessions
EXEC sp_who2;

SELECT
    [req].[session_id],
    [A].[Login] AS 'login',
    [A].[HostName] AS 'hostname',
    [req].[start_time],
    [cpu_time] AS 'cpu_time_ms',
    OBJECT_NAME([st].[objectid], [st].[dbid]) AS 'object_name',
    SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING([ST].text, ([req].[statement_start_offset] / 2) + 1, ((CASE [statement_end_offset]
                                                                                                   WHEN -1
                                                                                                       THEN DATALENGTH([ST].text)
                                                                                                       ELSE [req].[statement_end_offset]
                                                                                               END - [req].[statement_start_offset]) / 2) + 1), CHAR(10), ' '), CHAR(13), ' '), 1, 512) AS [statement_text],
    [ST].text AS 'full_query_text'
FROM
    sys.dm_exec_requests AS req
        CROSS APPLY
    sys.dm_exec_sql_text(req.sql_handle) AS ST
        LEFT JOIN @sessions AS A
            ON A.SPID = req.session_id
ORDER BY
    [cpu_time] DESC;
```

How it looks like:

[image: How it looks like #2]

Of course, it's possible to modify [code](https://github.com/amachanic/sp_whoisactive) from `Brent Ozar` answer so it would select a full query text, too, though. Nearly same technique is chosen [there](https://github.com/amachanic/sp_whoisactive/blob/master/who_is_active.sql#L538)(link of code of 18.07.2020 so might change after time):

[image: Code part from amachanic Git repo]

Comment: That's not a bug - that's by design. If you run it while the WAITFOR is executing, then the WAITFOR is the part that's active, so that's the query that'll return. That's why Adam's proc is called sp_WhoIsActive, not sp_WhoWillBeActiveLater. It shows the currently executing statement.

Comment: No one said it's a bug. It's okay, but someone might need a full text of query instead of short cut from it.

Comment: Sure, then just use get_outer_command = 1 parameter in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today and I don't know what causes it but I found a solution. I took the input parameter and saved it into a new parameter, i.e.

```
declare @parameter2 as x = @parameter
```

Then i changed the references to the parameter in the queries from @parameter to @parameter2.